# Слитное и раздельное написание НЕ (1)

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Прошу проверить выполнение задания:

(не)обоснованная критика — необоснованная критика
эти места (не)исследованы — эти места не исследованы
не(сходство)взглядов — несходство взглядов
не(согласен) с решением — не согласен с решением
(не)освещенная комната — неосвещенная комната
обстоятельство (не)выяснено — обстоятельство не выяснено
(не)теплый, а холодный ветер — не теплый, а холодный ветер
шёл (не)торопясь — шёл не торопясь
(не)дополучил баллов — недополучил баллов
(не)досмотрел фильм — не досмотрел фильм
ни на кого не(похож) — ни на кого не похож
еще (не)распустившаяся сирень — еще не распустившаяся сирень
(не)досмотрела за ребёнком — не досмотрела за ребенком

Это не домашнее задание: школа прошла давно, много забылось. Просьба поправить.

Comment: Здесь не выполняют домашних заданий. Дайте своё решение. Если будут проблемы, Вас поправят и объяснят ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка одна: недосмотрела за ребенком.

Приставка недо- со значением недостаточности действия: смотрела, но недостаточно, некачественно. Можно проверить: если бы была частица не с глаголом досмотреть, это было бы возможно в случае с досмотром багажа: Ваш багаж не досмотрели (не обыскали), а ребёнка не досматривают, за ним смотрят, присматривают.

Comment: "Ошибка одна: недосмотрела за ребенком". ==> Конечно ошибка, ведь если недосмотреть за ребенком, он может упасть или сунуть палец в розетку :)), А грамматически "недосмотрела за ребенком" — как раз правильно.

Comment: Я как раз о том, что у автора вопроса раздельно, а нужно слитно. Вы кому адресуете свой комментарий?